# Can I use nativebase.io reactnative package in expo manager workflow project?

Tags: react-native, native-base

I am trying to find a dropdown related react-native package. I couldnt able to find any, which is compatible with both IOS and android devices.

So planning to use nativebase.io reactNative package.
Is it okay to use or do I face any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can use `NativeBase` with the expo.
Expo has its own Picker component you can use that as well which works on both platforms, Nativebase Picker is also dependent on this core module of react-native, `So its recommended to use this one instead of installing a new UI lib only for Picker`.

https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/react-native/picker/